# folders and files are not visible after uploading file though multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, multer, unzip

I am working on a small project. discussing Step by step

1. At first I am uploading zip files though multer
2. extracting those files (How can I call extract function after completing upload using multer?)
3. After extracting those I am trying to filter those files
4. after filtering those files I want to move some files to another directory

in my main **index.js** I have

- A simple route to upload files which is working

```
// MAIN API ENDPOINT 
app.post("/api/zip-upload", upload, async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("FIles - ", req.files);
});
```

- Continuous checking for if there is any zip  file that needs to unzip but the problem is after uploading it's not showing any files or dir

```
// UNZIP FILES 
const dir = `${__dirname}/uploads`;
const files = fs.readdirSync("./uploads");

const filesUnzip = async () => {
    try {
        if (fs.existsSync(dir)) {
            console.log("files - ", files);
            for (const file of files) {
                console.log("file - ", file);
                try {
                    const extracted = await extract("./uploads/" + file, { dir: __dirname + "/uploads/" });
                    console.log("Extracted - ",extracted);
                    // const directories = await fs.statSync(dir + '/' + file).isDirectory();

                } catch (bufErr) {
                    // console.log("------------");
                    console.log(bufErr.syscall);
                }
            };

            // const directories = await files.filter(function (file) { return fs.statSync(dir + '/' + file).isDirectory(); });
            // console.log(directories);

        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    return;
}


setInterval(() => {
    filesUnzip();
}, 2000);
```

- Moving files to static directory but here is the same problem no directory found

```
const getAllDirs = async () => {
    // console.log(fs.existsSync(dir));
    // FIND ALL DIRECTORIES 
    if (fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        const directories = await files.filter(function (file) { return fs.statSync(dir + '/' + file).isDirectory(); });
        console.log("Directories - ",directories);
        if (directories.length > 0) {
            for (let d of directories) {
                const subdirFiles = fs.readdirSync("./uploads/" + d);
                for (let s of subdirFiles) {
                    if (s.toString().match(/\.xml$/gm) || s.toString().match(/\.xml$/gm) !== null) {
                        console.log("-- ", d + "/" + s);

                        const move = await fs.rename("uploads/" + d + "/" + s, __dirname + "/static/" + s, (err) => { console.log(err) });
                        console.log("Move - ", move);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
setInterval(getAllDirs, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many issues with your code, I don't know where to begin:

- Why are you using `fs.xxxSync()` methods if all your functions are `async`? Using `xxxSync()` methods is highly discouraged because it's blocking the server (ie parallel requests can't/won't be accepted while a sync reading is in progress). The fs module supports a [promise api](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) ...
- Your "Continuous checking" for new files is always checking the same (probably empty) `files` array because it seems you are executing `files = fs.readdirSync("./uploads");` only once (probably at server start, but I can't tell for sure because there isn't any context for that snippet)
- You shouldn't be polling that "uploads" directory. Because as writing a file (if done properly) is an asynchronous process, you may end up reading incomplete files. Instead you should trigger the unzipping from your endpoint handler. Once it is hit, `body.files` contains the files that have been uploaded. So you can simply use this array to start any further processing instead of frequently polling a directory.
- At some points you are using the callback version of the fs API (for instance `fs.rename()`. You cannot `await` a function that expects a callback. Again, use the promise api of fs.

**EDIT**

So I'm trying to address your issues. Maybe I can't solve all of them because of missing infomation, but you should get the general idea.

First of all, you shuld use the promise api of the `fs` module. And also for path manipulation, you should use the available `path` module, which will take care of some os specific issues.

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
```

Your API endpoint isn't currently returning anything. I suppose you stripped away some code, but still. Furthermore, you should trigger your filehandling from here, so you don't have to do directory polling, which is

1. error prone,
2. wasting resources and
3. if you do it synchronously like you do blocks the server

```
app.post("/api/zip-upload", upload, async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("FIles - ", req.files);

  //if you want to return the result only after the files have been
  //processed use await  
  await handleFiles(req.files);

  //if you want to return to the client immediately and process files
  //skip the await
  //handleFiles(req.files);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Handling the files seems to consist of two different steps:

1. unzipping the uploaded zip files
2. copying some of the extracted files into another directory

```
const source = path.join(".", "uploads");
const target = path.join(__dirname, "uploads");
const statics = path.join(__dirname, "statics");

const handleFiles = async (files) => {
  //a random folder, which will be unique for this upload request
  const tmpfolder = path.join(target, `tmp_${new Date().getTime()}`); 
  
  //create this folder
  await fs.mkdir(tmpfolder, {recursive: true});

  //extract all uploaded files to the folder
  //this will wait for a list of promises and resolve once all of them resolved, 
  await Promise.all(files.map(f => extract(path.join(source, f), { dir: tmpfolder })));

  await copyFiles(tmpfolder);

  //you probably should delete the uploaded zipfiles and the tempfolder 
  //after they have been handled
  await Promise.all(files.map(f => fs.unlink(path.join(source, f))));
  await fs.rmdir(tmpfolder, { recursive: true});
}

const copyFiles = async (tmpfolder) => {
  //get all files/directory names in the tmpfolder
  const allfiles = await fs.readdir(tmpfolder);
  //get their stats
  const stats = await Promise.all(allfiles.map(f => fs.stat(path.join(tmpfolder, f))));
  //filter directories only
  const dirs = allfiles.filter((_, i) => stats[i].isDirectory());

  for (let d of dirs) {
    //read all filenames in the subdirectory
    const files = await fs.readdir(path.join(tmpfolder, d)));
    //filter by extension .xml
    const xml = files.filter(x => path.extname(x) === ".xml");

    //move all xml files
    await Promise.all(xml.map(f => fs.rename(path.join(tmpfolder, d, f), path.join(statics, f))));
  }
}
```

That should do the trick. Of course you may notice there is no error handling with this code. You should add that.

And I'm not 100% sure about your paths. You should consider the following

- `./uploads` refers to a directory `uploads` in the current working directory (whereever that may be)
- `${__dirname}/uploads` refers to a directory `uploads` which is in *the same directory as the script file currently executing* Not sure if that is the directory you want ...
- `./uploads` and `${__dirname}/uploads` may point to the same folder or to completely different folders. No way knowing that without additional context.

Furthermore in your code you extract the ZIP files from `./uploads` to `${__dirname}/uploads` and then later try to copy XML files from `./uploads/xxx` to `${__dirname}/statics`, but there won't be any directory `xxx` in `./uploads` because you extracted the ZIP file to a (probably) completely different folder.

Comment: Can you please modify my code rather than explaining theoretically? Because I don't have that much knowledge of asynchronous js .